# Git flatten submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

Consider a project with the following structure

- Root

  - `submodule_a`

    - `common_submodule`
  - `submodule_b`

    - `common_submodule`

is it possible to add `submodule_a` and `submodule_b` in a way that they share the `common_submodule`. That is, I want the tree to look more like this:

- Root

  - `submodule_a`
  - `submodule_b`
  - `common_submodule`

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. The first step is to git clone the `common_submodule` so that it is placed next to your first level submodules `submodule_a` and `submodule_b`.

Now open your project in terminal and move in each of your submodules. Here you go on and add the cloned `common_submodule` folder as submodule:

```
git submodule add ../common_submodule
```

After you have done this in each of your first level submodules you've achieved what you have been looking for.

Note that you might fist need to delete the `common_submodule` in each of your first level submodules, before you re-add it again as described. There are plenty of StackOverflow questions that explain how to do that, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1260748/1280289).

Comment: Wouldn't this procedure remove `common_submodule` from `submodule_a` and `submodule_b`, so when any change to `submodule_a` or `submodule_b` is committed, these projects are no longer standalone?